# executing shell script in windows from scala

Tags: java, scala

The below line in my scala test is failing on windows 7 box

```
val worldId = s"$pwd/src/test/resources/startWorld.sh $extraPath".!!
```

My startWorld.sh looks something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

extra=""
if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
  extra="-v $1:/extra"
fi

ACTIVE=`docker-machine active 2>/dev/null`
HOST_IP=`docker-machine ip $ACTIVE`

# TODO: If HOST_IP not passed in, assume AWS and hit AWS's host-getter URL
#
docker run -d -P -v ~/.docker/machine/certs:/mnt/certs -e "DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=true" -e HOST_IP=$HOST_IP $extra test/world
```

I am getting below exception

```
Exception encountered when attempting to run a suite with class name: mc.test.ServiceTests *** ABORTED *** (61 milliseconds)
[info]   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\git\Conversation-Platform\microcore\microcore/src/test/resources/startWorld.sh": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: How are you trying to run bash in Windows? Are you using Cygwin?  Do you have a different bash interpreter installed?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the ProcessBuilder API, it runs through the standard windows `CreateProcess` mechanism which has no idea how to parse your hash-bang. As far as it's concerned, you're trying to run a nonsense binary. It doesn't matter whether you are running it from GitBash because it isn't using the shell to run the process. What you want to do is change your Scala to run something like `<path to your bash> <script name>`.